# errors with Javascript try catch

Tags: javascript

I wrote a project with Javascript and use try/catch as follows :

```
try{
        var params = {
            't_id': msg.from.username,
            0: config.botToken
        };
        request.post({
            url: urls.get('favorites'),
            json:true,
            body: {
                jsonrpc: '2.0',
                method: 'favorites',
                params: params,
                id: 1
            }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if(body.result == undefined)
                throw "other";

        });
    }catch(err)
    {
        let message = messages.getMessages(err);
        console.log(message);
    }
```

After starting the program, this error displayed :

> /var/www/html/marketer_bot/classes/Products.js:54
>                   throw "other";

Ex: `Products.js:54` refers to `throw "other";`

I dont know what's the problem! can you help me?

Comment: So you mean that you can't catch thrown exception?

Comment: body.result is undefined thats why it throws other

Comment: @Justinas Yes this was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're throwing in a callback that is executed asynchronously.  That means that block of code will be executed after your `try-catch` statement has already finished running.

You need to handle the errors in your callback while that callback is executing:

```
request.post({
  url: urls.get('favorites'),
  json:true,
  body: {
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    method: 'favorites',
    params: params,
    id: 1
  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if(body.result == undefined) {
    // handle error right here
  }
});
```